# バッジの説明の日本語訳

Tags: 討議, サポート, 翻訳

時間があったので、バッジの説明で英文だったものを翻訳してみました。
もし、よろしければどうぞ。
バッジ名は翻訳していません。

- `Explainer` - Edited and answered 1 question (both actions within 12 hours, answer score > 0)
  1つの質問に対して編集と回答を行った (どちらも 12時間以内に行い、回答スコアが 0より大きい )。
- `Refiner` - Edited and answered 50 questions (both actions within 12 hours, answer score > 0)
  50の質問に対して…（以降同じ）
- `Illuminator` - Edited and answered 500 questions (both actions within 12 hours, answer score > 0)
  500の質問に対して…（以降同じ）
- `自伝作家` - Completed "About Me" section of user profile
  ユーザープロファイルの"自分について"セクションを設定済み。
  ※ About Meの訳は編集ページに合わせた。
  ※ 別箇所でネットワークプロフィールとなっているので併せてユーザープロフィールの方がいいかもしれない？
- `コピー編集者` - Edited 500 posts (excluding own or deleted posts and tag edits)
  500件の投稿を編集した（自分の投稿の編集、削除された投稿、タグの編集を除く）